# Is it possible to use a mesh object to bevel a curve instead of another curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

When i try to use a mesh (like a cube for example) as a bevel target for a curve it doesn't let me select it. Am i missing something?

Comment: Curves bevel uses curves only. If you want a(some) cube(s) along the curve, add an array and curve modifiers to the cube.

Comment: ok, thank you, maybe i will try with a loopcut of the object and array

Comment: mmm... but if you've loopcuts in mind, you can also make the bevel curve a square...